# Why don't standard bike chains have inner/outer combo links so odd chain lengths are possible?

Tags: chain

I noticed while at an amusement park that on the roller coaster, each link of the chain has what can be considered a combination inner and outer plate.  The side plates are somewhat diagonal so they start as an outer then become an inner.  So my question is if these work well for roller coasters which have a lot of load, why not use a similar scaled down design for bikes so that odd length chains are possible?

Here is a pic of a roller coaster chain so you can see what I am talking about: (you can click on it for a more detailed larger pic).

[image: Roller coaster chain]

Maybe this design wont shift well?  I wonder what the main reason is.  Motorcycles also do not use it.  Maybe large pitch chains require it cuz being 2 links too long or short is a big difference but with a short pitch chain (1/2 inch or so), it is not so critical?

Comment: ...or you use a half link chain?

Comment: Mainly because it isn't necessary, and using the sort of links shown in your picture unnecessarily complicate things and would muck up modern indexed shifters.

Comment: Seems kinda odd that bikes don't normally use this type of chain, I have never seen this on any motorcycle, yet roller coasters DO use it.  If this design requires thicker side plates, why even use it on a chain that already is very heavy?  I wonder which design has more strength and if it is better to use the design like in the pic or have the side plates straight (slightly diagonal).  Very interesting from a mechanical viewpoint.  Maybe a Mechanical Engineer can chime in and explain that.  That chain is on a 48"x40" pallet so look how few links it takes to span it.  Impressive.

Comment: I wonder if this type of chain behave differently depending on if the wide or narrow part of the sideplates is the leading edge.  That is, are these type of chains directional (or at least slightly better in one direction than the other)?  I would think the narrow part is the leading edge so the part that moves forward.

Comment: Rollercoaster chains don't have low weight nor efficiency as their design goals.

Comment: @whatsisname - So how is the inner and outer alternating chain design more efficient than the "diagonal" design?  Where is the proof to back up that statement?

Comment: @David You have an answer to efficiency in the answer from Chris H.  Where is your *proof* a 1/2 is more efficient?  You repeatedly put out a concept with an attitude of prove why it won't work rather than accept logical answers.

Comment: So I could ask a "converse" question... Why do rollercoaster chains use this chain where every link is the same concept if inner/outer alternating is cheaper, simpler to make, and possibly lighter?

Comment: @David And I suspect you will find way to *ask* that question based on a on some *assertion* with no proof.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bike chains have to have some other method to take up the error (like horizontal dropouts or tensioners even on a single speed).

They'd still need this if the maximum error was halved, so you wouldn't really gain anything. Chains would need thicker walls as the  walls would no longer be in pure tension (the force would tend to straighten them). This would make the chain heavier and wider, neither of which is desirable. It would also be more expensive as parts would have to be stamped then bent rather than just stamped.

Comment: But there are 1/2 link bike chains http://kmcchain.us/chaintype/half-link-series-12x18/

Comment: @Frisbee true.  They're all 1/8" chains as you say in your answer, which are heavier to start with than 3/32" and not so fussy about external width, therefore the plates can be a touch thicker.  They also don't have to handle shifting.  But they're still (from a quick search) a niche item and even the manufacturer doesn't give any real reaosn to use them.  The Q and my A should probably have been about "rare" rather than "never".

Comment: Actually you can get them in 3/32 http://kmcchain.us/chain/hl810-gold/ Manufacturer does not list a reason to use any of the series

Comment: @Chris H, single speed bikes could benefit from this.  The chain could be cut to an odd length, perhaps making the rear axle be in a desired position such as being as forward as possible.  For motorcycle final drive (sprockets and chain), it can be used to control the wheelbase which has an effect of how the motorcycle handles.  2 links on a bike (1/2" each so 1" total) if added or removed will change the rear axle position by about half of that or 1/2".  With a combo in/out chain on every link, 1 link would only move the rear axle forwards or backwards 1/4" on a single speed bike.  Nice.

Comment: Also I really don't like that term "half-link".  In reality, each pin spans a full link.  Alternating inner and outer links are actually a 2 link repeating pattern.  The term "half-link" is misleading.  They should just call those links and call the alternating inner and outer link double link chain (implying it must be an even length unless some special master link is used).  If I go to a motorcycle shop and want my chain cut, I can tell them to remove 4 links and they know exactly what I am talking about.  4 links would be 2 outers and 2 inners removed.

Comment: @David: the half-links purpose in life is to make single speeds possible in frames with really short or vertical dropouts. If you have a derailleur they are completely useless.

Comment: I wouldn't say completely useless.  Seems like a more simple and versatile design.  Maybe they are more expensive to make thus to save cost, they use the alternating (inner and outer) design.

Comment: @David for manufacture, the alternating design is considerably easier. The bent-plate design is only conceptually simpler.

Comment: @whatsisname Those statements are not true. When a 1/2 link is used they typically have the option for a full adjustment.  The main use is BMX, trick, street, trials ... that want an exact set up (it may or may not be of real value).  It would not be completely useless on a derailleur as there could be an edge case of you could get the range with an odd number.  But the edge cases in no way justify the down side of the design in a derailleur application.  David seems to have this concept of anything that can conceptually be done should be done.  It is not worth debating with him.

Comment: I am not saying all my concepts should be done.  I just asked why the bike chains are this way and I haven't heard a good argument yet as to why these wont shift well.  What would cause them not to work well with cogs, derailleurs...?

Comment: @David - Indexed shifters rely on the pin ends sticking out of the links to engage "ramps" on the sides of cogs to assist shifting.  (Note the chain shown in Frisbee's answer does not have pins, but rivets of a sort.)  Without the pin and ramp scheme indexed shifting would be impossible.  I suppose you could have similar pins with half links, but I suspect the setup would not be as stable and reliable.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm confused by your use of the term "indexed shifting". I thought that "indexed" just means that the gear system is set up to move the derailleur a fixed distance at a time, which corresponds to the distance to the next cog on the cassette, as distinct from the old-style downtube shifters where the lever moved continuously and you had to "feel" where the next gear was. Why does indexing specifically need the pin ends on the chain?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Why do you think indexed shifting was not invented immediately after derailleur shifting?  Because, with standard chains and cogs, one needs to "overshift" to shift up to a larger cog.  Indexed shifting was not the "invention".  Rather, it was what one might call "assisted shifting", where the chain pins engaging in the ramps on the sides of the cogs lift the chain to the next larger cog.  Without this feature indexed shifting is impossible.  (This feature also makes it possible to shift under load, something not possible previously.)

Answer (score 6):

But you do see it in BMX, track, and fixie
You don't see it in narrow chians as have a derailleur to take up slack

[image: half link design]

Comment: I don't see how this design would interfere with shifting as a "standard" chain has alternating inner and outer plates so the maximum width of the chain should be about the same for both designs.

Comment: @David Chalk it up as yet another disappointment in modern bicycle design for you.   Could and should are not the same.  So you don't like the term half link - stackexchange cannot fix that.

Comment: Sure they could.  Don't use a term if it is not accurate and/or it is misleading.   Use better names.

Comment: @David I get "could and should are not the same" is foreign logic to you. Can't help you.  I *could* fly east to get from NY to LA. And could is verb.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is there is no technical reason one way or the other. Its likely a light weight half link will actually stretch while under tension unless its more expensive or heavier than a full link chain.  (Roller coaster chains don't have to be light weight so its less of a problem.). If its a material difference in performance I do not know. Its entirely possible to engineer a half chain to work with derailleurs, so that is not a reason not to do it.

What I do know s half link chains cost more. Maybe they only make high quality Half Links, and you cannot buy cheap versions, or maybe they cost more for the same quality. However many people buy on price. On one web site I looked at, Half link chains start at $25, Full link chains start at $8.  Manufacturers don't use half link chains, and most people faced with that difference would need a fairly compelling reason to change to a different chain type from manufacture given the price difference. This could be more about inertia in the supply chain rather than manufacturing cost.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good point about the half links stretching, due to the bend in the plates.

Comment: "Entirely possible to engineer a half chain to work with derailleurs"?  That would introduce a few  non trivial challenges.

Comment: Technically chains do not stretch, rather they elongate due to wear.  They are not rubber bands.

Comment: @David. A normal bike chain the plates are flat, so at their maximum tensile strength. The 'stretch' I refer to would happen, as the bent plate under tension will straighten out under tension, depending on the metal and thickness will depend if it fully returns to its original form or eventually it becomes permanent